# $X∈M_{m×1}(F)$ and $Y∈M_{1×n}(F)$: A Range Dimension Implication

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Let $A \in M_{m \times n}(F)$. To prove that $\operatorname{rank}(A) \le 1$ if and only if there exist $X \in M_{m \times 1}(F)$ and $Y \in M_{1 \times n}(F)$ such that $A=XY$ where must I start?

Comment: do not post ads-like text in the title

Comment: What is $F$? Why the tags (abstract-algebra), (functional-analysis)? Even (vector-spaces) seems incorrect here.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo A melting pot theory?

Comment: Can there be a negative dimension? There are really only two options here, right? Namely $0$ or $1$.

Answer (score 2):

If $A=XY$ then we have $A=\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\\vdots\\x_m\end{pmatrix}*\begin{pmatrix}y_1&\ldots&y_n\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}X_1y_1&\ldots&x_1Y_n\\\ldots\\ \ldots\\ \ldots
\\x_m y_1&....&x_m y_n \end{pmatrix}$ so rank of A $\le  1$

on the other hand:

if $\text{rank} A \le 1$ so other (m-1)row  are linear combination of for example first row so $A=\begin{pmatrix}y_1&,....,&y_n\\x_1y_1&,...,&x_1y_n\\........\\x_my_1,....x_my_n\end{pmatrix}=X*Y $such that $X=\begin{pmatrix}1\\x_1\\..\\x_m\end{pmatrix}$ and $Y=\begin{pmatrix}y_1&....&y_n \end{pmatrix}$

Comment: excuse me if it has incorrect format because i can only  see original latex style

Comment: \begin{whatever} something \end{whatever} isn't nested in cash symbols, I think. Try that out.

Comment: today my net has problem but i will try to revise it

Answer (score 0):

Hint: I am not sure for every $F$, but I heard that for $F=\mathbb R$ we have $\operatorname{rank}(A)=k$ iff there exist non-degenerated real matrices $L$ and $R$ of respective sizes such that $LAR=\Lambda$, where $\Lambda$ is a diagonal matrix with first $k$ elements equal to $1$ and others to $0$.